# Sort out 4 numbers using only if else statement and else if on javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to sort out 4 numbers using only if else and else if how can I do that on javascript without using sort function?

Comment: What have you tried? Insert some code, expected result versus actual result, error messages?

Answer (score 0):

With *nothing* more than `if` and `else` (and presumably assignment statements or some other way you can swap elements), the only way to sort is really to unroll a sort loop into individual comparisons.

Here's some pseudo-code that does it for three elements:

```
if element[0] > element[1]:  # swap 0/1 if needed
    temp = element[1]
    element[1] = element[0]
    element[0] = temp

if element[1] > element[2]:  # swap 1/2 if needed
    temp = element[2]
    element[2] = element[1]
    element[1] = temp

if element[0] > element[1]:  # swap 0/1 if needed
    temp = element[1]
    element[1] = element[0]
    element[0] = temp
```

Obviously, that becomes far more onerous once you have more than three elements, becoming (I'll just do the comments):

```
# swap 0/1 if needed
# swap 1/2 if needed
# swap 2/3 if needed

# swap 0/1 if needed
# swap 1/2 if needed

# swap 0/1 if needed
```

Anything beyond that (or, to be honest, even that) should probably be done with loops or an in-built sort method if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [7,4,6,3];

function swap(a, i, j) {
    var tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j]
    a[j] = tmp;
}

if (a[0] > a[3]) {
    swap(a, 0, 3);
}

if (a[1] > a[3]) {
    swap(a, 1, 3);
}

if (a[2] > a[3]) {
    swap(a, 2, 3);
}

if (a[0] > a[2]) {
    swap(a, 0, 2);
}

if (a[1] > a[2]) {
    swap(a, 1, 2);
}

if (a[0] > a[1]) {
    swap(a, 0, 1);
}
```